Use @font-face to replace the font determined by system-ui, not by a font family name
For example, a web page use such a CSS code:
font-family: {'Segoe UI', sans-serif;}

Meanwhile, I don't like Segoe UI, so I can replace it to another local font with @font-face: (inject it with extensions like Stylus. I am user of that web page, not its developer)
@font-face {font-family: Segoe UI; src: local("my own font");}

However, what if that Segoe UI is not determined by font family name while it's determined by system-ui? (Segoe UI is the default font on Windows)
font-family: {system-ui, sans-serif;}

This CSS code doesn't work:
@font-face {font-family: system-ui; src: local("my own font");}

Neither does this:
@font-face {font-family: Segoe UI; src: local("my own font");}


I mean, what you are trying to do is know better than whoever made the decision to match the system UI? You might not like it, but you can't just replace a system font. If the code is yours, just define a different font-family, perhaps in a CSS variable. But no, you cannot redefine a system font I think. That would defeat the purpose of having a system font to reference...

There's a minor privacy issue with this. Doing this would enable you to (indirectly) determine what the system font is set to which, it turn, can help with fingerprinting individual systems.
